# I would like to use DOM but now I have errors

Tags: html, css

I would like to get information when I put buttons, for this I use DOM, but I have errors, how can I solve this problems?

I tried to confirm if name is correct, and search about DOM, but I couldn't figure out it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="uft-8">
    <title>Pomodoro Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="menu">menu</p>
    <p class="timer">0.00</p>
    <button data-option='start' class="timer_button" >start</button>
    <button data-option='stop'  class="timer_button">stop</button>
    <button data-option='reset' class="timer_button">reset</button>
    <script>
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-option]');

    function test(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    buttons.forEach(()=>buttons.addEventListener('click',test));


    </script>
</body>
```

I would like to see the results in the console when I put the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

```
buttons.forEach((button)=>button.addEventListener('click',test))
```

The `buttons` is a list. When you iterate over it with `forEach` you can get each button as the first argument of the method. And that is where you must attach the event handler.

Comment: It was solved thanks to you, thank you so much, I appreciate you.